# Dúvida Tag Form

Tags: c#, html, html5, asp.net

Possuo duas tags <kbd>form</kbd> em uma página para validar alguns campos que aparecem no modal, o primeiro `form`, é apenas para pesquisar no `grid`. O `button` de abrir o modal, e o de remover o filtro funcionam perfeitamente.

Porém, ao abrir o modal, o `buton` que envia os dados não funciona, ele apenas fecha o modal. E se eu coloco ele (o botão) dentro da tag `form`, ele (o `form`) dá erro como se não tivesse preenchido.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <div id="contact-form" class="panel panel-default">
            <div style="text-align: center;" class="panel-heading">
              <p class="panel-title">
                <asp:Label ID="Label78" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" Text="Agendar Avaliação Física"></asp:Label>
              </p>
            </div>

            <form id="form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Hora"></asp:Label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtHora" runat="server" class="form-control" required="required" onblur="Verifica_Hora(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                      <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-1">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label250" runat="server" Text="Data"></asp:Label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server" class="form-control" onblur="limparDataInvalida(this);" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                      <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Observação"></asp:Label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <textarea id="txtObeservacao" cols="20" rows="2" runat="server" class="form-control" style="resize: none"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <asp:Button ID="btnGravar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-block" Text="Gravar" OnClick="btnGravar_Click" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ele deveria salvar, no código eu salvo os dados no banco ou altero, como posso fazer funcionar?

Comment: Isso é `asp.net` `webforms`, correto? Você fala de 2 forms, mas só mostra um deles, mas o que _ dá erro_ ao tentar salvar, como você falou é o primeiro form. Entendi correto?

Comment: É este, o outro form, os buttons são só para consulta, e as consultas são realizadas corretamente, inclusive o button de abrir o modal, está dentro do primeiro form, este é o segundo. Este é o button que tem a função salvando os campos no onclick, porém não funciona <asp:Button ID="btnGravar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-block" Text="Gravar" OnClick="btnGravar_Click" />

Comment: Então está acontecendo algum erro no `btnGravar_Click`. Você tentou ver se algum erro está sendo disparado lá?

Comment: Sim, se ele está dentro do form, ele aparece como se os campos não tivessem preenchidos, mesmo estando preenchido, e quando está fora desse form, ele não faz nada.

Comment: Falta o `runat="server"` no seu form, contúdo você não deve ter mais de um `<form>` por página no WebForms. o ideal seria você transpor a sua modal para um UserControl (.ascx)

Comment: Quando coloco o runat="server" no form que preciso que grave os dados no banco, ele me retorna o seguinte erro 'Página só pode ter uma marca Form do servidor.'

Comment: @LeandroAngelo tem algum exemplo que possa me auxiliar ?

Comment: @marianac_costa se ninguém responder antes, à noite eu deixo um exemplo como resposta

Comment: Conseguir resolver @LeandroAngelo obrigado.

Comment: @marianac_costa Seria legal você postar a sua solução como resposta ou então remover a pergunta, mas aconselho a primeira opção pois assim estará ajudando outras pessoas que venham a enfrentar o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver, colocando ao clicar no button, ativar o required, e quando concluo a operação, ou fecho o modal, eu coloco desativo o required, funcionou perfeitamente, não precisei criar outra tag form, e muito menos criar outra função, eu pensei em criar outras tagform para validar cada form, mas estava ficando inviável, pois não fazia funcionar. 
Ao abrir o modal:

```js
 function openModal() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            ($("#<%=txtHora.ClientID %>").prop('required', true));
            ($("#<%=txtData.ClientID %>").prop('required', true));
            ($("#<%=txtassunto.ClientID %>").prop('required', true));
        }
```

E quando fechava o modal, ou era concluído a operação:

```js
  function Campos() {
            ($("#<%=txtHora.ClientID %>").prop('required', false));
            ($("#<%=txtData.ClientID %>").prop('required', false));
            ($("#<%=txtassunto.ClientID %>").prop('required', false));
         }
```